# Swift 2.1: Unable to map JSON object to Realm object using ObjectMapper

Tags: swift, swift2, realm, swifty-json, objectmapper

I am trying to map my JSON object to a Realm object using ObjectMapper, but I keep getting nil.

```
import RealmSwift
import ObjectMapper

class Notification: Object, Mappable {
dynamic var id = 0
dynamic var isProcessed = false
dynamic var type = ""
var supersedes : Int?

required convenience init?(_ map: Map) {
    self.init()
}

// Mappable
func mapping(map: Map) {
    id <- map["id"]
    isProcessed <- map["isProcessed"]
    type <- map["type"]
    supersedes <- map["supersedes"]
}
}
```

I am using the following line of code to map the incoming JSON to the above Realm object.

```
let notif = Mapper<Notification>().map(notification) // notif here is nil
```

notification is a JSON object (SwiftyJSON library used)

Sample Notification JSON:

```
  {
        data =             {
            buyerInfo =                 {
                image = "";
                name = "";
                userId = UID2268351488;
            };
            sellerSKUs =                 (
                                    {
                    id = SSK236123228808967424;
                    price =                         {
                        amount = 888;
                        currency = THB;
                    };
                    quantity = 2;
                },
                                    {
                    id = SSK563365068895040768;
                    price =                         {
                        amount = 6865;
                        currency = THB;
                    };
                    quantity = 1;
                }
            );
            subOrderId = SOD751798094080240;
        };
        id = 39038;
        isProcessed = 0;
        supersedes = "<null>";
        type = PendingSubOrderConfirmationNotification;
    },
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

You can't combine ObjectMapper and SwiftyJSON in that way.
Either you provide the `rawValue` from the SwityJSON `JSON` struct as argument to ObjectMapper's `Mapper.map` or you use instead just [`NSJSONSerialization`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/).